# Temporal and spatial sympathy when casting Postcognition

Tags: spells, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, mage-the-awakening

The Time 2 spell Postcognition allows a mage to view the past. However there are some confusing factors (emphasis mine):

> She can review the past of her current location or any moment in her
>   own past, or that of an object, with flawless clarity. To focus this
>   sense on something or someplace other than the mage’s current physical
>   location, the mage must also use Space 2. **Without the use of Space 2,
>   she can do this only for an exact spot in which she was or is.** [..]
>   and casting dice pool is modified by temporal sympathy

Scenario: You find a stolen painting in a crime lord's collection. You know when it was stolen and touching the object you try to view the moment it was taken from the museum to identify the thief.

- If you have never been to the museum and only heard of the theft, you will need Space 2, that is clear. However if you have visited it once (Encountered level sympathy), is this requirement lifted?
- If you need Space 2, are you penalized for both spatial and temporal sympathy (that of the object, here both Intimate, giving you -4)?
- If you must use *your own* temporal sympathy to the target location, does having access to the actual object help you any?

Comment: Observation: the physical location the museum is in now isn't the physical location where it was during the desired-to-be-viewed event, just like the painting's physical location now and then is not the same. If the book says relative to what the physical locations are measured, that is likely to be applicable to this question.

Comment: @vicky_molokh 1. I believe position is measured relative to the Gaiasphere / Earth. If not, there are practically no places you have been to (ie. most of them are in space). 2. I do not understand your last sentence.

Comment: 'review the past of her current location or any moment in her own past, or that of an object' implies that it's possible to 'anchor' the view to the *object* rather than the *place*, which would eliminate the need for Space *if* that is so. I'm just not familiar with the edition's stance to conclude whether it is fully so. Also, 'something or someplace other than the mage’s current physical location' implies that both a place *and* a thing (such as a painting) can be considered equivalent to the mage's current location. Or at least looks like it probably does.

Comment: @vicky_molokh In what way do you think a thing would be "equivalent to the mage's current location"?

Comment: If it's possible to view the past of a place (like a museum or of the Gaiasphere) despite the place now being in a different physical location than the past, this *implies* that it's possible to do the same with another object too. But this is conjecture on my behalf, as I am not aware of more explicit statements of underlying principles which would confirm or deny this implication. But hopefully it would be a useful direction for investigation.

Comment: @vicky_molokh The problem is that to define position you need a frame of reference and one is as valid as the other. It makes sense to choose the Earth and in this view the museum does not change position.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that you must have a temporal sympathy to the object. That means without space 2 you can only cast only yourself, or something you are touching (which includes the space you currently exist within).

So you can look at the past of a painting even when it was in another location. You can look at the past of your current location or you can look at your own past.

You have strong temporal sympathies to all of those histories because you are physically connected to them while casting the spell.

Frame of reference as we would understand from physics doesn't apply at all. The rules of the Space (and Time) Arcana are all that matter.